# Use jQuery to determine when Django's filter_horizontal changes and then get the new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a filter_horizontal selector in my Django admin that has a list of categories for products (this is on a product page in the admin). I want to change how the product change form looks based on the category or categories that are chosen in the filter_horizontal box.

I want to call a function every time a category is moved from the from or to section of the filter_horizontal.

What I have now is:

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

    function toggleAttributeSection(choices) {
        $.getJSON('/ajax/category-type/', { id: choices}, function (data, jqXHR) {
            // check the data and make changes according to the choices
        });
    }

    // The id in the assignment below is correct, but maybe I need to add option[]??
    var $category = $('#id_category_to');
    $category.change(function(){
        toggleAttributeSection($(this).val());
    });
});
})(django.jQuery);
```

The function never gets called when I move categories from the left side to the right side, or vice versa, of the filter_horizontal.

I assume that $category.change() is not correct, but I don't know what other events might be triggered when the filter_horizontal is changed. Also, I know there are multiple options inside of the select box. I haven't gotten that far yet, but how do I ensure all of them are passed to the function?

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Here is how it is done if anyone stumbles on this question. You need to listen for change events on both the _from and _to fields in the Django filter_horizontal and use a timeout to allow the Django javascript to finish running before you pull the contents of the _from or _to fields. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
var $category = $('#id_category_to');
$category.change(function(){
    setTimeout(function () { toggleAttributeSection(getFilterCategoryIds()) }, 500);
});
var $avail_category = $('#id_category_from');
$avail_category.change(function(){
    setTimeout(function () { toggleAttributeSection(getFilterCategoryIds()) }, 500);
});
```

And this is how I get the contents of the _to field:

```
function getFilterCategoryIds() {
    var x = document.getElementById("id_category_to");
    var counti;
    var ids = [];
    for (counti = 0; counti < x.length; counti++) {
        ids.push(x.options[counti].value);
    }
    return ids;
}
```

I know it was a convoluted question and answer and people won't come across this often but hopefully it helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the SelectBox.redisplay function in a scope like so:

```
(function() {
    var oldRedisplay = SelectBox.redisplay;
    SelectBox.redisplay = function(id) {
        oldRedisplay.call(this, id);
        // do something
    };
})();
```

Make sure to apply this after SelectBox has been initialized on the page and every time a select box refreshes (option moves, filter is added, etc.) your new function will be called.

(Code courtesy of Cork on #jquery)